# Appengine cron.yaml definitions not showing in developer console

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I have a basic appengine project with multiple modules and a dispatch.yaml:

- my-project/boxes/app.yaml  (default module)
- my-project/users/app.yaml  (users module)
- my-project/dispatch.yaml

I'm trying to configure a single hourly cronjob with the following definition:

```
cron:
- description: hourly box purging
  url: /api/boxes.purge
  schedule: every 1 hours
  target: default
```

I've tried adding it to the module it concerns, so put the above definition in file: 'my-project/boxes/cron.yaml' and running `appcfg.py cron_info boxes/`. My terminal seems to indicate all went well:

```
hourly box purging:
URL: /api/boxes.purge
Schedule: every 1 hours (UTC)
2015-04-30 10:08:00Z, 0:59:55 from now
2015-04-30 11:08:00Z, 1:59:55 from now
2015-04-30 12:08:00Z, 2:59:55 from now
2015-04-30 13:08:00Z, 3:59:55 from now
2015-04-30 14:08:00Z, 4:59:55 from now
```

Ye the Appengine Developer console fails to reflect this and cron jobs are not run. It does show on the local development panel.

Putting the definition in the root of the projects (besides dispatch.yaml) yields the same results. Other things i've tried (in vain): Redeploying all code, `appcfg.py update_dispatch`, waiting a while before refreshing the developer console.

Hopefull someone is able to help me find the obvious mistake, or confirm that their is some bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [Configuration](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Configuration) section of the doc it's stated:

> Optional application-level configuration files (dispatch.yaml,
>   cron.yaml, index.yaml, and queue.yaml) are included in the top level
>   app directory.

I agree, the paragraph context appears to leave room for interpretation (**typically...**). But the quoted text also indicates that these files are considered app-level configs. So I'd keep them at the top.

About the update: I noticed, for example, that the index.yaml file was **NOT** uploaded with the rest of the multi-module app at my first deployment, I had to explicitly use **appcfg.py update_indexes**. This was not happening with a single module app. Maybe **appcfg.py update_cron** also needs to be explicit?

Comment: In the end I got it to work at some point, I THINK it was because i ran 'appcfg.py update' or 'appcfg.py update_cron' so I think you were correct, i was unable to reproduce the effect. It worked btw while keeping my cron.yaml neatly in the designated module folder.